# How many Custom Post Types to register?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

My current WordPress site only exists of pages. The structure is as simple as this:

```
example.com/hotels 
example.com/attractions 
example.com/restaurants
```

I want to use Custom Post Types to add listings about individual hotels, attractions and restaurants. The new structure will look like this:

```
example.com/hotels/myhotel 
example.com/attractions/myattraction 
example.com/restaurants/myrestaurant
```

With myhotel/myattraction/myrestaurant being a Custom Post Type.

All listings share the exact same custom fields.

My Question: 
Do I need to create 3 Custom Post Types (hotel/attraction/restaurant) or should I register just 1 "global" custom post type - eg called "Place" - and specify if its a hotel/attraction/restaurant using hierarchical Custom Taxonomies?

What are the advantages/disadvantages of these different approaches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would structure it like a CPT for each Hotels, Attractions, Restaurants. Then a custom taxonomy that ties them together for instance "Places" with children like "Locations", etc.

If the site has a lot of connected data it is a really good idea to sketch out the relationships on paper or using software like Visio so you can visually see how it all fits.

Comment: Why would you prefer create a CPT for each item? Maybe for flexibility in the long run? Or is there another reason?

Viseo is a good idea, I´ve been using Excel but it´s not very visual.

Comment: The reason I would thing the top levels items as CPT's is it's very likely the display data is very different , for instance a Restaurant page would not have the same stuff as a Hotel page.